# Renderscript and the GPU

Tags: gpu, renderscript

I *know* that Renderscript's design is to obscure the fact about what processor I'm running on, but is there any way to write the code such that on GPU-compute-capable devices (at the moment, Nexus 10), it *will* run on the GPU? Is there any way to tell that a script's function is running on the GPU?

www.leapconf.com/downloads/LihuaZhang-MulticoreWare.pdf suggests that if I don't use globals, I don't use recursion, and don't call rsDebug anywhere in a kernel, it will be run on the GPU; is that correct?

I'd love to see a short script that people have somehow verified will run on the gpu as a purely compute-based task (eg., no graphics work).

Comment: This question really does deserve more upvotes, as I think Android is leaving too many things in the dark here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, those claims about Nexus 10's behavior are correct. There are some other things about calling some of the RS runtime functions (for example, don't call rsGetAllocation) that would cause the CPU to run a function. However, I think globals that aren't allocations or bound pointers are okay in 4.2.

Going forward, a lot of those restrictions are going to be relaxed (globals being the big one).

In terms of seeing where a kernel runs: there's not much you can do with 4.2 to figure that out. We haven't seen a compelling reason to do so yet, but if this turns out to be really important it's something we could add without too much difficulty via something like systrace. Feel free to complain to us if you can demonstrate why that's hurting you beyond "I assume the code will run faster on the GPU."

I'm pretty sure that the Mandelbrot implementation in ImageProcessing (fw/base/tests/RenderScriptTests/ImageProcessing/) runs on the GPU in 4.2.

Comment: Tim, can you give an update on what is the status in Android 4.3 wrt the original question?

Comment: Accessing global allocations and using GetElementAt and SetElementAt won't cause the kernel to be run on the CPU in the vast majority of situations on Nexus 10 running 4.3. There are some limitations with USAGE_SHARED, but that's more potential copy overhead than falling back to the CPU.

Comment: What if an element(or thread?) accesses neighbour elements data? Would it run on gpu?